# How to use two moment, one for current time and another for start time?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

```js
var oldTime = document.querySelector('#oldtime');
var currentTime = document.querySelector('#currenttime');

const FetchTimeFromDb = '2018-07-18T03:07:13.384Z';

setInterval(function() {
oldTime.innerHTML = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
currentTime.innerHTML = moment(FetchTimeFromDb).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="oldtime"></div>
<div id="currenttime"></div>
```

I have a bug in my application, Where i format my start time with moment

```
const starttime = moment('2018-07-18T03:07:13.384Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH;MM:ss');
```

and i get the current time using `const now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss')`
where first declaration change the time entirely and keep looping in the old time. Even i reverse the steps, it gives me same result. I am keeping my start time in database using ISO8601 format and when i send to server, i convert to the format for that server. Is there proper solution to handle this kind of situation?

There is nothing wrong with the code.
I found out that in my string format there is a typo.it suppose to be ('YYYY-MM-DD HH:**mm**:ss') instead of ('YYYY-MM-DD HH:**MM**:ss') which is why always set to 07.

Comment: Could you reproduce it in a JSFiddle or SO snippet?

Comment: Could you show us results

Comment: i added the link.

Comment: I am not getting your expected output please explain in detail which kind of expected output you want?

Comment: let's assume right now in my pc, it's '18-7-2018 14:22:57', and my previous time '2018-07-18T03:07:13.384Z' and I format and get '2018-07-18 11:07:13'. So it shoule be getting current time: '18-7-2018 14:22' and old time:  '2018-07-18 11:07:13'. Instead I am getting current time: '18-7-2018 14:07:44' and old time:  '2018-07-18 11:07:13'.

Comment: I think the problem i am facing is when i format my old time. it change my current time. it appears that it set the minutes to old minutes